# Check whether Regex match is within multi-line comment

Tags: regex

I'm having a set of matches within a file and want to find out which of those matches are within comments (between `/*` and `*/`). Is this something I can do with regular expressions?

I was thinking about `/\*.*MATCH.*\*/`, however, this also matches the situation `/* comment */ MATCH /* some other comment */`. Is there a correct way to do this?

Note that `MATCH` can occur multiple times inside the file (within and not within comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the previos lookahead-answer works, it does not work for multiple MATCH occurrences in the file. Therefore I found a better, non-Regex-based, solution:

```
var lastCommentStartBefore = content.LastIndexOf("/*", match.Index);
var lastCommentEndBefore = content.LastIndexOf("*/", match.Index);
if (lastCommentEndBefore < lastCommentStartBefore)
    // within comment
```

Comment: Please post this with the relevant code inside the question. This is really a bad practice not providing all relevant details and then posting an answer that is featuring an incomplete piece of code out of nowhere.

Comment: I added the detail that "MATCH" can occur multiple times. I don't know which code I should add to the question. The code in the answer is not incomplete...

Comment: Not incomplete? What is the language you are writing it in? What type does the `match` variable have? How is it declared? What does it hold?

Answer (score 0):

```
\/\*(?:(?!\/\*|\*\/)[\s\S])*\bMATCH\b(?:(?!\/\*|\*\/)[\s\S])*\*\/
```

You can use `lookahead` based regex here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/3

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `.*` is greedy and will match as many characters as possible. Instead, try using lazy matching `*?`:

```
\/\*[^\/\*]*?MATCH[^\/\*]*?(\*\/)
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/yH6sJ6/1).